# Why doesn't shell expansion on popd remove a directory from stack?

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution, pushd

When I use `popd` alone it removes a directory from the stack and takes me to that directory. However, if I do `cd $(popd)` then no directory is removed from the stack.

Since the process is simply forked and the result is put in place of the shell expansion, why isn't a directory taken off of the stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command substitution `$(…)` runs the command in a subshell. A subshell starts out as an identical¹ copy of the main shell, but from that point on the main shell and the subshell live their own life.

1. The shell process creates a pipe and forks.
2. The child runs `popd` with its output connected to the pipe, then exits.
3. The parent reads the data from the pipe and substitutes it into the command line.

Since `popd` runs in the child process, its effect is limited to the child process. The directory *is* taken off the stack — off the child's stack. Nothing happens to the stack in the parent.

¹  <sub>Nearly identical; the differences are not relevant here.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

The syntax `$(...)` isn't "shell expansion", it is "command substitution".

With this syntax a sub-shell is created, the command inside is executed and the stdout returned on the comamnd line.  So, for example,

```
x=$(cd /tmp ; ls)
```

will run the `cd` command in the subshell, which means the current directory of the main process is left untouched.

In a similar way, `cd $(popd)` will cause the `popd` to run in the child process and so impacts only the child process; the parent process is untouched.

You can see that it has affected the child process with this simple test:

```
$ pushd /tmp
/tmp ~
$ pushd /
/ /tmp ~
$ dirs
/ /tmp ~
$ cd $(popd ; dirs >&2)
/tmp ~
$ dirs
/tmp /tmp ~
```

The `dirs >&2` shows that inside the `$(...)` shell the directory stack has been popped, but because this is a *child* process the parent stack is untouched.

Comment: Nitpick: `$(…)` *is* shell expansion — specifically, it's the part of shell expansion that is called command substitution.

Answer (score 3):

`pushd` and `popd` keep the stack in a variable called `DIRSTACK`, which changes in your subshell, but stays unchanged in the parent shell, just like any other environment variable.

[Further read](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/pushd_popd_and_dirs.shtml).